# VB.NET Multithreaded SerialPort SMS Delay

Tags: vb.net

Wanna ask if how can I can create a delay without using System.Thread.Sleep(interval).

My apps serves as server runs in a endless loop that reads SMSINBOX using serialport to interface with a GSM MODEM..  readSMSINBOX() is followed by a delay ... The problem here is the delay thats kills me.... It hangs all the controls of my app. Other functions aside from reading, is sending, userMANAGEMENT, console, etc. Any idea how I can implement a delay that consumes time WITHOUT hanging the app by using SYSTEM.TIMERS or SYSTEM.THREADING or BACKGROUNDworker... Please... I can't post all my codes here.. Don't know either how to publish my code in a live site. Just a pure NOOB..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by delay? Is your goal to fire readSMSINBOX() periodically, let's say every 30 seconds?

Comment: thanks rokjarc for your concern. yes exactly... but `readINBOX()` and `sendMESSAGE()` are functions in my apps that uses `SYSTEM.THREADING.THREAD.SLEEP()` which hangs the UI Thread that **hangs** (NOT RESPONDING) all of the controls of the app. That's the problem... What exactly is a delay that may be executed with a different thread but also _consumes time_.  i need this to allow access to controls such as cmdButtons, txtbox, tabs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the timer should do exactly what you need (it doesn't block the UI).

Exact implementation of timer depends on version of VB.NET you're using but
you can find a good (and downloadable) example of using timers here: [Working with Timer Control in VB.NET](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/TimerControl04262005033148AM/TimerControl.aspx)

You'll have to import `System.Timers`

`myTimer` can be variable in the code of main form

```
Timer myTimer
```

You can set it up and start it in `Form1_load`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

   myTimer = new Timer(30000)
   myTimer.Enabled = true 
   addhandler myTimer.Tick,addressof OnTimerEvent

End Sub
```

And your (tick) handler would be something like:

```
Private Sub OnTimerEvent(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

  'here you can call you communication routines

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much rokjarc... but how can i change the delay interval when firing OnTimerEvent()?

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you very much rokjarc... got it already.... Thanks man.. you helped me a lot... :-D

Comment: Oh, and nothing says thanks like accepting the answer ;) it also closes this topic as answered. If your question is answered, of course. Do the same with other of your questions if they were properly answered.